# How to return a view and also return a json response in Laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, view, response

I'm trying to return both the view and a json response.

```
return view('website.ajaxcart.cart-list', compact('cartProducts'));
return response()->json([
    'status'=>"success",
    'message' => "Product added to Cart"
]);
```

Tried to connect these two like this:

```
return view('website.ajaxcart.cart-list', compact('cartProducts'))->response()->json([
    'status'=>"success",
    'message' => "Product added to Cart"
]);
```

But it's not working... Is it even possible?

Comment: You cannot. What are you trying to achieve? If you a product is added to cart and you want to display success message in the view, best use a `redirect` and send message using `->with('message', 'Product added to Cart successfully');`

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
  return redirect('website.ajaxcart.cart-list', compact('cartProducts'))
  ->with('success', 'Profile updated!');
```

In blade file

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

please go through laravel documentation

Answer (score 0):

**JSON** is text, written with **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation.
It has its own format.
So when you push anything on json response, then you break this format.

You can pass an array as the `json` response. So craft an array based on your data and use it, like this :

```
$user= User::all()->toArray();
$post= Post::all()->toArray();
return Response::json(array('user' => $user, 'post' => $post));
```

So in your code just pass it as an array instead of `JSON` :

```
$data = [
    'status'=>"success",
    'message' => "Image deleted"
];

return view('website.ajaxcart.cart-list', compact('cartProducts', 'data');
```